# DataGridView error : The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, thread-safety

My windows application is crashing, as a background thread is trying to update the form even after form got disposed. My code is as below

```
if (IsDisposed || dataGridIncidentView.IsDisposed)
                   return;

               if (dataGridIncidentView.InvokeRequired)
               {
                   dataGridIncidentView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { rowIndex = dataGridIncidentView.Rows.Add("val1","val2"); }));
               }
               else
               {
                   rowIndex = dataGridIncidentView.Rows.Add("val1", "val2");
               }
```

The error in event log is :

> The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.InvalidOperationException Stack:    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean,
>   System.Object[])    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(System.Object[])
>   ..... ..... .....

I've put a IsDisposed check on asyncCallBack function. But all these checks are not handling all the cases. Could anybody suggest me, how to resolve it ?

Thanks,

Abhinav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `IsDisposed` check inside the delegate.

IE:

```
delegate { 
  if (!IsDisposed) rowIndex = dataGridIncidentView.Rows.Add("val1","val2"); 
}
```